# Fermat numbers. Are they all prime?

Tags: number-theory

It was once believed that all numbers of the form $$2^{2^n}+1$$ were prime until Euler disproved this by showing that $$2^{2^5}+1$$ is not prime. Is there a formula or a way to know which of the Fermat numbers are prime?.

Comment: May I suggest you change the title to _Fermat numbers: Are they all prime?_  :)

Answer (score 4):

The only known Fermat primes so far are the cases $n = 0,1,2,3,4$. You can get some more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number).

Comment: The probability, that no other fermat primes exist, is very high. So, probably, Fermat was not only wrong, but the opposite of his conjecture seems to be true.

Comment: The least fermat number for which it is not known, whether it is prime, is $F_{33}$.

Comment: It is very unlikely that a formula exists, which tells us, which fermat numbers are prime.

Comment: There is Pepin's test which is a primailty test. 


There might be a way to prove the finiteness of the set of Fermat primes. Let $P(n)$ be the number of prime factors of the nth Fermat number. If $P(n+1) \ge P(n)$ for large enough $n$, then there are only finitely many Fermat primes. If $n=32$ is large enough, then 65537 is the last Fermat prime.

Answer (score 0):

Something like a formula exists in [Pepin's Test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9pin%27s_test), whereby $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ is prime iff $3^{2^{2^n-1}}\equiv -1\bmod F_n$.  In principle, this is simple to implement as it involves just repeated squaring.  But for Fermat numbers of current interest the numbers are so large that the computation becomes nontrivial.

Comment: The lowest possible $n$ for which $F_{n}$ may be prime is $n=33$.

Is there a list of how many prime factors each Fermat number from $F_{5} to F_{32}$ has? There may be a clue.

Comment: @MichaelEjercito Fermat numbers tend to be so large that trial division (restricting to a suitable arithmetic progression of primes) is often the only feasible approach.  So all of the larger Fermat numbers that are known to be composite tend to be only partially factored.  For $n=20$ we don't even know any factors, just that it's not prime (via Pepin).  It looks like $n=11$ is the largest fully-factored one, per https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatNumber.html.  Even if it's out of date, I doubt the state of the art has advanced by more than $1$ position.

Comment: [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatNumber.html) currently includes $F_{33}$ as a known composite.